# How do you determine where to cast when fly fishing bigger, mostly featureless rivers?

Tags: rivers, fly-fishing

Smaller streams are easy to tell where to cast when fly fishing given fish's tendency to hang out in pools or hole or undercut banks. It easy to decide where you need to cast and approximately where the fish are going to strike.

However on bigger rivers, it's not anywhere nearly so obvious where to cast, are there tricks to guessing where the fish will be?

Comment: Which type of fish are you after - I'm guessing trout (rainbow? brown?) or salmon given that you are fly fishing, but you could also be after greyling, pike, bass, carp etc.

Comment: @bob1 Mostly the trout family

Comment: I fish for striped bass with a fly rod. Along beaches you can often read subsurface features by the way the water moves above (and down current) them. Target these areas as you would target eddies and the backs of rocks on small streams.